# Can a method within a class be generator?

Tags: python, methods, generator

Is it acceptable/Pythonic to use a method in a class as a generator? All the examples I have found show the yield statement in a function, not in a class.

Here is an example working code:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def first_ten(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield i

    def test(self):
        for i in self.first_ten():
            print i

SomeClass().test()
```

Comment: I would guess that most examples are functions because that's simpler; you don't need to be in a class, so it isn't shown.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, this is perfectly normal. For example, it is commonly used to implement an [`object.__iter__()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) to make an object an iterable:

```
class SomeContainer(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        for elem in self._datastructure:
            if elem.visible:
                yield elem.value
```

However, don't feel limited by that common pattern; anything that requires iteration is a candidate for a generator method.

Comment: +1 that iterator pattern is a good example. http://www.diveintopython3.net/ by Mark Pilgrim covers some of this.

Comment: If you are getting `TypeError: 'SomeContainer' object is not an iterator`, you are probably trying something like `sc = SomeContainer` with `next(sc)` to get each value.  Instead do `sc_iter = iter(sc)` and then `next(sc_iter)`.  See (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-cookbook-3rd/9781449357337/ch04.html).

Comment: You mean `sc = SomeContajner()`, probably :-) Yes, `SomeContainer()` instances are iterable, they are not an iterator object. `next()` requires an iterator, and `iter()` produces an iiterator from an iterable. The difference is that an iterable can produce any number of iterators, but iterators are single-use.