# Why I can't use a method class as a generator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I am in a very strange situation. I know I can use a method class as a generator as I have done it before. 
In this other question [Can a method within a class be generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349439/can-a-method-within-a-class-be-generator) someone asks for the same thing and they say that yes, it can be done.

However, I get an error when I try it. Here is a minimal example:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def first_ten(self):
        for i in range(10):
            yield i

a = SomeClass();
next(a.first_ten)
```

'method' object is not an iterator

why? How is this possible?
Thank you
edited: fixed code indentation

Comment: why the negative vote? What is wrong with my question exactly?

Comment: The clue is in "'method' object is not an iterator"... you need to call the method... `it = a.first_ten()` then use such as `next(it)` for instance... or `for n in a.first_ten(): print(a)` etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the method:

```
a = SomeClass()
it = a.first_ten()
next(it)
```

The reason for this is that the method is not itself a generator.  It is a *generator function* that returns a new generator every time it is called.

The same applies for non-method generator functions as well.  Note the types in this snippet:

```
>>> def f():
...     yield from range(10)
...
>>> type(f)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(f())
<class 'generator'>
```

Comment: Another alternative, that would prevent the need for calling, would be if it was declared as a `@property`